# Problem in complex analysis regarding pairwise distinct roots of a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem:** Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open set and $a_0, \dots, a_n : D \to \mathbb{C}$ continuous complex functions. For $w \in D$ we defne a polynomial
$$p_w (z) = a_n (w) z^n + \dots + a_1 (w)z + a_0(w).$$
Suppose that there exists $w_0 \in D$ such that $p_{w_0}$ has pairwise distinct zeroes and $a_n(w_0) \neq 0$.
Prove that there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $w_0$ such that $p_w$ has pairwise distinct zeroes for every $w$ in that neighborhood.

I realize that the setup of this problem hints at Rouche's theorem but I still have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: No need for Rouche's Theorem. The roots are distintc iff $p_w'(z) \neq 0$ at the roots of $p_w$. Since $p_w'$ is a continuous function such a neighborhood exists.

Comment: But then you have to show that the roots of $p_{w}$ are close to the roots of $p_{w_0}$, and I couldn't immediately see why this would be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n$ complex roots $r_1(w),...,r_n(w)$ of $p_w(z)$ depend continuously on the coefficients $a_1(w),...,a_n(w)$ (which in turn are assumed to depend continuously on $w$).

If we assume that there is a $w_0\in \mathbb{C}$ so that all roots are distinct, we can calculate something like $$g(w) = \min \{|r_i(w)-r_j(w)| : 1\leq i\neq j\leq n\},$$

from which we know $g(w_0)>0$. As a composition of continuous functions, $g$ is again continuous, and so we find a neighbourhood of $w_0$ for which $g(w)>0$ is still fulfilled.

**EDIT** About the continuous dependency of the roots on the coefficients:
Let's just view the coefficients $a_0,...,a_n\in\mathbb{C}$ of $p(z) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_kz^k$ as independent variables, i.e. we look at the function
$$\Phi : \mathbb{C}^{n+1}\times\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C} , \quad (a_0,...,a_n,z)\mapsto \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_kz^k.$$
Then $\Phi(\cdot,\cdot)$ is continuously differentiable and due to the initial assumption we know that there exists a point $(a',z') := (a_0',...,a_n',z')\in \mathbb{C}^{n+1}\times\mathbb{C}$ so that $$\Phi(a',z') = 0. $$
Also, due to the additional assumption that all roots are distinct, we have  $$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial z}(a',z') = \frac{d p}{d z}(z')\neq 0.$$

So due to the implicit function theorem, we find open neighbourhoods $U_{a'}\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ and $U_{z'}\subset\mathbb{C}$ with $(a',z')\in U_{a'}\times U_{z'}$ and also a continuous(ly differentiable) function $\varphi : U_{a'}\rightarrow U_{z'}$, so that $$\Phi(a,z) = 0 \Leftrightarrow z = \varphi(a) \quad \forall (a,z)\in U_{a'}\times U_{z'},$$

i.e. the root $z$ depends continuously on the coefficients $a_0,...,a_n\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Why do complex roots depend continuously on the coefficients?

Comment: @the_dude in general they do not, but for polynomials they do: Just consider $\Phi(a_0,...,a_n,z) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_kz^k$ which is a polynomial in $n+2$ variables and thus continuous. So when perturbing the coefficients, the values of $\Phi$ change continuously

Comment: I'm probably being annoying, but I'm still not completely convinced. Obviously the values of a polynomial change continuously as we're changing the coefficients, but I'm still not convinced why that would imply that the zeroes would be "close together". I'm gonna give you an accepted answer in any case, but I would just like to clear up this small detail.

Comment: @the_dude No problem, I am sure I'm just as annoying when asking questions on here ^^ 
I think the standard way to proof this continuous dependency is the implicit function theorem. The comment doesn't have enough space for the argument, so I'll put it into my original post as an edit.